# Should I use static initializer or super class

Tags: java

I have a interface named `Parser`. Two classes `ParserA, ParserB` implements `Parser`.

```
public interface Parser{
     public void initialize();
     public int Parse(byte[] data);
}
```

I have confusion with initialization. `ParserA` initializes two `Maps`. `ParserB` initializes two `Maps`. But differentData. `Maps` are initialized with constant data. Means not from runtime.

So Should I use approach1 or 2?

Approach1:

```
class Initializer{
  //have two maps as member
}

Class ParserA extents initializer implements Parser{
       public int Parse(byte[] data){

       }

       public void initialize(){
         //Initialize those maps
       }
}

Similarly for class B
```

Approach2:

```
class Constants{
   //Static initializer of four maps[two for ParserA, two for ParserB]
}

Class ParserA implements Parser{
       public int Parse(byte[] data){

       }

       public void initialize(){
          //Constants.map1 likewise use.
       }
}

Similarly for class B
```

Which is preferred in the above use case?

**Q2:** I have another utility method in the class `Initializer`. Let it be `getAttr` which makes use of those two maps. In this scenario, which approach is better?

**Q3** If I want `multiple threads to use these parsers`and assume I choose approach 1, unnecessary intiailization occurs on each thread. This is what really confusing me.

I am bit more confused.

Assume `Animal` is a base class for `Tiger, Lion`. Each Animal will have `age, numOfLegs` as members. It will make sense to have `Animal` class rather than having `age, numOfLegs` in each Animal class. So `Superclass` wins here. Isn't? If so, My scenario also similar to this I assume.

Comment: On Q2 the getAttr method accesses both maps or ParserA.getAttr accesses parserA's map and parserB ParserB's?

Comment: Go with the second option.

Comment: @FrancescLordan Yes. ParserA.getAttr accesses parserA's map and parserB ParserB's

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for opinion, here is my 2 cents:

Both the approaches seem unnecessary. The basic idea of the `Parser` interface itself seems a little wrong. If the parsers are going to be statically initialized, why do you expect the users of the parser to call `initialize` method? What would the program do if they don't call `initialize` and use `parse` method?

The purpose of the `Parser` interface is to parse a byte[]. Individual implementations should initialize themselves with whatever the logic they want. So, I would suggest that, you remove the initialize method in `Parser` and have the `ParserA` and `ParserB` initialize it with the Maps (or whatever they might need) when they are created.

Something like:

```
public interface Parser {
    int parser(byte[] data);
}

public class ParserA implements Praser {

    public ParserA() {
        //initialize the maps they use or whatever the data structure that is needed
    }

    public int parser(byte[] data) {
        //logic of parsing
    }
}
```

//similarly for ParserB.

For your Q2: If you don't expose the internal DS and the state of the DS is immutable these Parsers can be shared with multiple threads without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a third option

```
Class ParserA{
    // two maps declaration
    static {
         // maps initialization
    }

    public int ParseA(byte[] data){
        //parse the byte array
     }

    public xxxx getAttr(){

    }
}
```

The static block is only executed when the class loader loads the class, that only happens once regardless the number of threads. That allows you to initialize the static attributes of each parser.